# What process powers the progress bar during initial boot?

Tags: startup, launchd, macos, efi

I recently learned that launchd was written and used starting with Mac OS X Tiger.

Before it's inception the progress bar would actually give useful information about what process was currently being executed. However, starting with OS X Tiger the progress bar was managed by the *WaitingForLoginWindow* process.

You can read about this on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) and the source of the citation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd).

Originally, the length of time required for the progress bar to complete was based off of the time that elapsed during the last successful boot as is described below

> *WaitingForLoginWindow* writes the number of seconds it displayed the progress bar during the most recent system boot to /var/db/loginwindow.boottime. Theoretically, you could chart this value over time to measure boot performance, and maybe fire off an email if it goes over a certain percentage (I’m thinking of 10.4 Server users here).

I can't find any information on whether or not this is the same method used now. All of the information that I can find comes from ~2005-2008.

Is this still the method that is used in macOS to display the progress bar? *WaitingForLoginWindow* is no longer located in /usr/libexec/.

If this is the method still used, what is happening when the progress bar stops and hangs?